# Async in MVC Controller, multiple await i need

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync()
        {
            ShowUploadFiles objFiles = new Helpers.ShowUploadFiles();
            ShowComments objComments = new Helpers.ShowComments();
            TempData["FileUploaded"] = await objFiles.ShowUploadeFiles();
            return View("Index", await objComments.GetListofCommentsfromTable());
        }
```

Trying to implement Async in my Controller.
  I have to call ShowUploadFiles() which is to be saved in Tempdata and GetListofCommentsfromTable() to be called and pass it as Model.

How can i impelement Async to both as Tempdata and Model has to be loaded independently.

Do I have to update as

```
public async Task<List<BlobModel>> ShowUploadeFilesAsync()
        {
           //Some operation
           return await (List<BlobModel>);

         }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync()
 {
     ShowUploadFiles objFiles = new Helpers.ShowUploadFiles();
     var showUploadeFilesTask = objFiles.ShowUploadeFiles();

     ShowComments objComments = new Helpers.ShowComments();
     var getListofCommentsfromTableTask = objComments.GetListofCommentsfromTable();

     await Task.WhenAll(showUploadeFilesTask, getListofCommentsfromTableTask);

     TempData["FileUploaded"] = showUploadeFilesTask.Result;
     return View("Index", getListofCommentsfromTableTask.Result);
 }
```